# Can't get blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload and ZF2 running

Tags: jquery, file, frameworks, zend-framework2, uploading

Has anybody expierience with  'blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload' in combination with Zend Framework 2? I am struggeling to get is working.

The form seems to do his thing and works but when the controllers wants to do his magic, I am stuck.

This is my function that is called by the script to upload and save the files.

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $files =  $request->getFiles();
    $httpadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

    if($httpadapter->isValid()) {

        $httpadapter->setDestination('data/images/uploads/');
        $httpadapter->receive($files);

        $return = 'valid';

    } else {
        // Form not valid, but file uploads might be valid...
        // Get the temporary file information to show the user in the view
        $return = $httpadapter->getMessages();
    }


    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array($return));
}
```

The return I get is:

```
[{"fileUploadErrorFileNotFound":"File images1.jpeg was not found"}]
```

print_r($files) gives me this output:

```
Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
[storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
    (
        [files] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => images1.jpeg
                        [type] => image/jpeg
                        [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpa3IOwX
                        [error] => 0
                        [size] => 10185
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Can anybody help me so I can upload files?

greetings,

Answer (score -1):

Your snippet works fine for me, it must be something else.

For instance, the adapter adds a **validator** `\Zend\Validator\File\Upload`. This is actually where your error comes from: [Upload.php#L32](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/File/Upload.php#L32), which is thrown here: [Upload.php#L158](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/File/Upload.php#L158). I am very curious what is happening in your situation, and why it throws the error. Could you do some **prints from the validator**?

*It basically means that the files array in the validator is not the same array as the one you printed or the parameters passed to the validator are no good.*

Also, which **version of zf** are you using?

---

On a sidenote you can reduce your code slightly, there's no need to pass the files array, as `\Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http` converts the $_FILES itself.

```
$httpadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();

if($httpadapter->isValid()) {

    $httpadapter->setDestination('data/images/uploads/');
    $httpadapter->receive();

    $return = 'valid';

} else {
    // Form not valid, but file uploads might be valid...
    // Get the temporary file information to show the user in the view
    $return = $httpadapter->getMessages();
}

return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array($return));
```

You can also check a single file ( which blueimp should post ), by passing the field name as a parameter to `isValid()` and `receive()`

```
// ...
if($httpadapter->isValid('upload_name')) {
    // ...
    $httpadapter->receive('upload_name');
    // ...
}
```